# OWL rdfs:langString maxCardinality per language

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, ontology, rdfs

Is it possible in OWL to have a maximum cardinality restriction on a language property, which would limit the cardinality per language.

For example, I only want at most one `dct:title` per language. So,

```
:demo dct:title "Demo"@en, "Demo"@nl.
```

would be OK, but

```
:bad_demo dct:title "Bad demo"@en, "Wrong demo"@en.
```

would give an error?

Comment: "per language" is not possible in OWL as you don't have access to the language tag.

Comment: you can use SPARQL to get the violations: `select ?s ?lang (group_concat(?o; separator = "; ") as ?values) {
?s dct:title ?o
BIND(lang(?o) as ?lang)
} 
group by ?s ?lang
having (count(?o) > 1)` - and maybe put it into a SHACL rule which is the "better" constraint language for RDF data

Comment: @AKSW:  Actually, it is possible to express the restriction within the OWL 2 RDF-based semantics. However, you would need a very special reasoner to enforce it.

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann well, to be fair, I was assuming to write a generic statement. I know that it's possible to do it for a specific language, but who wants to enumerate the same datarange restriction for all possible language tags? I'm always thinking in OWL 2 DL as I'm not aware of any OWL Full reasoner (yes, you could rewrite to FOL and use a reasoner for FOL, but who wants this?). And for me, OWL is not a constraint language so nowadays I'd mostly suggest to use SHACL for RDF data if you really want to define and validate constraint.

Comment: I'll upvote your answer (when seing your efforts) and sorry for my to generic statement that it doesn't work in OWL. Should be more precise in my next statements.

Comment: If by "OWL Full reasoner" you mean "correct and complete wrt the OWL RDF-based semantics", then you cannot be aware of some as it is impossible to make one, even in theory. If "OWL Full reasoner" includes incomplete reasoners, then all RDF / RDFS / OWL RL and more reasoners are OWL Full reasoners. You surely know some of them.

Comment: BTW, for the use case described by Nathan Cox, I agree that SHACL is the way to go. Using OWL for this is silly.

Answer (score 7):

You can partly do this in OWL 2 DL. However, you would have to add a cardinality constraint for each language you use. In OWL 2 DL, you cannot have a general axiom that would work for all possible languages. In Turtle syntax:

```
@base <http://example.com/>.
@prefix dct:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>.
@prefix owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>.
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>.
@prefix xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>.

<>  a  owl:Ontology;
  rdfs:comment  "An ontology with cardinality restrictions on some languages."@en .
<ThingWithTitle>  a  owl:Class;
  rdfs:subClassOf  [
    a  owl:Restriction;
    owl:onProperty  dct:title;
    owl:maxQualifiedCardinality  1;
    owl:onDataRange  [
      a  rdfs:Datatype;
      owl:onDatatype  rdf:plainLiteral;
      owl:withRestrictions  ([rdf:langRange "en"])
    ]
  ], [
    a  owl:Restriction;
    owl:onProperty  dct:title;
    owl:maxQualifiedCardinality  1;
    owl:onDataRange  [
      a  rdfs:Datatype;
      owl:onDatatype  rdf:plainLiteral;
      owl:withRestrictions  ([rdf:langRange "nl"])
    ]
  ], [
    # ...
    # same for de, es, fr, it, zh, etc.
    # ...
  ]
].
```

With this ontology, the following would be inconsistent:

```
<doc1>  a  <ThingWithTitle>;
  dct:title  "Title"@en, "Another title"@en-UK .
```

You could be more specific and allow multiple English/Dutch titles as long as they are not in the same dialect. Just replace `rdf:langRange "en"` by `rdf:langRange "en-UK"` etc.

In OWL 2 Full, you can express this generically (that is, for all languages), but it's awfully complicated and there is no reasoner on Earth that can deal with this type of reasoning, so it's better not trying, unless you like academic challenges for the sake of intellectual masturbation.

**Edit:**

After some intense mental masturbation, I came up with the following:

```
[ 
  owl:onDatatype  xsd:string;
  owl:withRestrictions  (
    [
      xsd:pattern  "...regular_expression_for_an_extended_language_range_from_rfc_4647..."
    ]
  )
]  rdfs:subClassOf  [
  owl:onProperty  [owl:inverseOf rdf:langRange];
  owl:someValuesFrom  [
    owl:onProperty  [owl:inverseOf rdf:first];
    owl:someValuesFrom  [
      owl:onProperty  [owl:inverseOf  owl:withRestrictions];
      owl:someValuesFrom  [
        owl:intersectionOf  (
          [
            owl:onProperty  owl:onDatatype;
            owl:hasValue  rdf:plainLiteral
          ], [
            owl:onProperty  [owl:inverseOf  owl:onDataRange];
            owl:someValuesFrom  [
              owl:intersectionOf  (
                [
                  owl:onProperty  owl:maxQualifiedCardinality;
                  owl:hasValue  1
                ], [
                  owl:onProperty  owl:onProperty;
                  owl:hasValue  dct:title
                ], [
                  owl:onProperty  [owl:inverseOf  rdfs:subClassOf];
                  owl:hasValue  <ThingWithTitle>
                ]
              )
            ]
          ]
        )
      ]
    ]
  ]
] .
```

Verifying that it works within the [OWL 2 RDF-based semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-rdf-based-semantics/) is left as an exercise to the reader.